# Using cx_Freeze with Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, cx-freeze

So I'm running 32 bit 3.4 python and wrote a script that functions properly when run but I am trying to turn it into an exe file using cx_Freeze. Here is my setup code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import pandas

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

setup(name='VPN_Decoder',
      version = '1.0',
      options = {'build_exe':{"packages":['tkinter','pandas']}},
      executables = [Executable("VPN Decoder.py", base=base)])
```

When I run it through the build process it doesn't return any errors but when I go to open the exe it returns:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sr581.jpg

I tested the setup script with another piece of code that i wrote and it worked perfectly the first time so I know the problem has something to do with this specific script. More specifically it seems to be when I try to import the pandas module. That is when I import pandas in the code itself, it still works fine if I don't import pandas in the script but do import it in the setup file.

This is my first time using cx_Freeze or trying to go through this process at all so I haven't really been able to decipher what is causing the error. Any help would be much appreciated!